# Unusual behavior regarding "detached entity passed to persist" exception when trying to persist a detached object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple model class like this

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    String name;
    

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I am trying to persist instance of User class detached (when the id of the transient object is not null).

I was expecting "detached entity passed to persist" exception, however I am not getting that, for this code

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("u2");
u.setId(2);
repo.save(u);
```

Here the id is not null, I should get a detached entity passed to persist exception Can somebody explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Spring data is not the same as JPA but a wrapper or a collection of utilities (or so) to ease the use of JPA related stuff and `EntityManager`.

Meaning also that `Repository` is not the same as `EntityManager`. So how are those two related?

If you take a look at the source code of `SimpleJpaRepository`

> Default implementation of the {@link org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository} interface

you will see there:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Tracing after some more classes for `entityInformation.isNew(entity)` leads to `AbstractPersistable` and method:

```
@Transient
public boolean isNew() {
    return null == getId();
}
```

It will not try to *persist* entity that has an Id set but *merge*.